# How to Get pantone color number from pdf?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, colors, acrobat, adobe-illustrator

I want to extract pantone colors from PDf from illustrator.dll  or acrobat.dll. It is possible to get pantone colors from adobe professional . but I don't know how to get through code. I used illustrator too. can you please help me to get pantone colors using csharp code.
I had extracted font size from PDF using Illustrator . Is it possible to get pantone color ? thank you in advance

```
Illustrator.TextFrame tF = doc.TextFrames[i];
Illustrator.TextFont objFont = tF.TextRange.CharacterAttributes.TextFont;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very nice to obtain that kind of information and still rely on it as it is in reality.

Usually Pantone colours can only be seen on their official catalogues, as colours on digital surfaces tend to be converted to the screen crystal cells format.

Anyway, you've even got a comparison tool on their site I think, but my advice as a Designer is not to rely on those colours, as a simple tweak on a colour can sometimes ruin hours of work.

Here is a simples site I found: http://www.ginifab.com/feeds/pms/cmyk_to_pantone.php

Good Luck ;)